# GMP: converting integer to std::string

Tags: c++, stdstring, gmp

Does GMP‌ have any function for converting std strings to integers?

Function [`mpz_init_set_str`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Simultaneous-Integer-Init-_0026-Assign.html) initialize and converts char* to int.
I want to know are there any support for std strings?

Comment: "_Function mpz_init_set_str initialize and converts char* to int._" `std::string` has `.c_str ()`, which yields `const char*`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the c_str() function to access the underlying char array :

```
std::string str;
mpz_t strg;
mpz_init_set_str(strg, str.c_str(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

GMP has C++ bindings so use gmpxx and it will work without any problems.
Simple assignments will do the job (so no boiler plate code).

[Even introduction](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html) shows such example:

> ```
> int
> main (void)
> {
>   mpz_class a, b, c;
>
>   a = 1234;
>   b = "-5678";
>   c = a+b;
>   cout << "sum is " << c << "\n";
>   cout << "absolute value is " << abs(c) << "\n";
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: And this should also work directly with std::string (no need for `.c_str()`), since that's what the OP was asking.